# Image does not change on mouse over using jquery function

Tags: php, jquery, html

```
 <a href="#">
    <div class="col-md-5 campaigns" id="hoverimg">
      <img class="featurette-image img-responsive" src="images/tee1.png" >     
        <li class="progressbar">
           <p>
               <!--<strong>Orders Completed</strong>--> <span class="pull-right small muted">78%</span>
           </p> 
           <div class="progress tight">
                <div class="bar" style="width: 78%;">
                </div>
           </div>
        </li>
        <div class="prodheading">
            <h2>Heading 1</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

jQuery code:

```
<script>
             $('document').ready(function ()
         {
             $(function ()
             {
                $("#hoverimg")
                    .mouseover(function ()
                     {
                         var src = $(this).attr("src").match(/[^\.]+/) + "images/tee2.png";
                         $(this).attr("src", src);
                     })
                     .mouseout(function ()
                     {
                         var src = $(this).attr("src").replace("images/tee2.png");
                         $(this).attr("src", src);
                     });
             });
});

 </script>
```

I am not getting the real problem behind this.

Comment: Why have you commented out all your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JavaScript is completely commented out by having `//` in front of every line. These will have to be removed if you want anything to happen.

There are some issues:

`.replace()` is a JavaScript String method and requires two arguments:

1. the regular expression and
2. the replacement string.

`.match(/[^\.]+/) + "images/tee2.png` probably does not work as you expect it to do: `.match(/[^\.]+/)` will return the first part of the string it is applied on that does not cointain a dot (`'.'`). Is this really what you want to do?

example:

```
"path/subpath/filename.ext".match(/[^\.]+/) + "images/tee2.png"
```

will return

```
"path/subpath/filenameimages/tee2.png"
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with `.match(/[^\.]+/)` ?

Answer (score 1):

You have applied the id to the `div` tag and in jquery you are trying to get the `src`. You must assign the `id` to the `img` tag.

Comment: ya before ur comment i just corrected it thanks for ur support

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#hoverimg1").hover(
     function() {$(this).attr("src","images/teee2.png");}, 
     function() {$(this).attr("src","images/teee1.png");
   });
```

Comment: Is this how you solved the problem, a response to one of the answers or an addition to your question? Please add some explanation to your post. Just a code dump is seldom useful.